# Silverlight Image Positioning/Transformation

Tags: silverlight, image, transformation

What I would like to do is the following:
Change the points of the four corners of an image.

What is possible now, is to change the top left corner. But that will only move the image.
I want to transform the image by changing the corner coordinates.
The effect will be a 3d-kind transformation. 
A skew transformation will not do, I want to be able to position the corners freely.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just place corners of an image arbitarily and have it distort accordingly.  It might be better if you specified the effect you are trying to acheive.

There are couple of options which may or may not suit.

1. Would a [`Matrix3DProjection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.matrix3dprojection(VS.95).aspx) serve your purpose (as well as do a lot a math for you)?
2. Would using the image to Fill a path or using a path to clip the image get the effect you want.

Comment: I'm guessing that what I want to do is a non affine transformation on a rectangle. 
Your second suggestion might work, did a quick test earlier.